# Mounting a PDF via wicket

Tags: java, wicket, document, mount

I am new to wicket and need to load a PDF, using Java and Wicket, when a user enters a URL. For example, typing in the URL:

www.domain.com/pdf/myDocument

will force the document www.domain.com/pdf/myDocument.pdf to be loaded

The reason for doing this is that I have a bunch of PDF documents in the webapp folder of my Java project. A printed letter that is being mailed to customers has a link to one of these documents but is missing the PDF file extension. I therefore need to put something in place that intercepts this URL and load the appropriate PDF resource.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/. You can load with webApplication.getServletContext().getResource(parameters.get(0).toString() + ".pdf")